# "To Be or Not to Be" about variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, null

Just doing a little introduction to JavaScript. I'm used to more than often testing the existence of my pointers in C++ so as not to crash.

Never did I read Hamlet, but I read [this page](http://blog.jails.fr/index.php?post/2009/12/01/undefined-/-null-in-JavaScript) about `null` and `undefined` in JavaScript.

And in a Nutshell I can:

```
if (varname == null)
if (varname === null)
if (typeof(varname) != 'undefined') 
if (varname != undefined)
if ('varname' in object) 
if (object.hasOwnProperty('varname'))
```

Honestly that is a little too much for me :). What is the classical way in JavaScript for testing variables so as to avoid crashes?

Comment: *Much Ado About Nothing* might be another play to read :-)

Comment: i never needed to test that in javascript o.O

Comment: @Renanlf And your scripts always work seamlessly ?

Comment: Yep... Works fine... But i don't remember doing something really different then setting some CSS or values or properties for HTML tags... The most elaborated code was an Radix Sort in javascript... So i never worried about that

Comment: It's bogus to say you never had to worry about that. That's like saying you were born with the knowledge. I'd say the answers below show this is not a simple matter and it was a good question,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because of errors thrown reading undeclared globals, checking a variable is best done using the third example, the `typeof` example.

```
if (varname == null)
```

will tell you whether the value is defined and nullish and throw an error if undeclared.

```
if (varname === null)
```

will tell you if the value is defined and exactly null and throw an error if undeclared.

```
if (typeof(varname) != 'undefined')
```

will tell you if the variable is defined or not without throwing an error.

```
if (varname != undefined)
```

is the opposite of the first.

```
if ('varname' in object)
```

will tell you if the object has a property either in itself or somewhere along its prototype chain.  This is not guaranteed to work for host objects.

```
if (object.hasOwnProperty('varname'))
```

will tell you if the object has an own property, ignoring the prototype chain.
This will break if a property named 'hasOwnProperty' has been set.

```
if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(object, 'varname'))
```

is a more reliable version of the last.

Comment: There is too much fuss about when `varname` is undeclared - most likely you **want** an error to be thrown because a typo was made. `varname == null` is one of the most useful tests, as it works for `null` and `undefined`. Good answer nonetheless +1.

Comment: I second this.  Variables should never, ever be undeclared.

Comment: @Box9, often you are correct.  I got the impression the OP was asking how to feature test, but if not specifically related to feature testing, then you're right.

Comment: +1 Very complete answer.  As a practical matter, though, all that's required in most cases is a simple `if (a)`... see my post below.

Answer (score 3):

the usual way is to use the truthyness of values.

```
if(varname){

}
```

This covers most of the examples you gave

Comment: True, but note that if the variable contains zero, or the empty string, it's also treated as `false` ...

Comment: -1: Will fail with "varname is not defined" if... well, varname is undefined ;-)

Comment: @Capsule argh... isnt there any one line statement ?

Comment: This is often NOT what you want. You will end up rejecting perfectly legitimate values such as 0 or false.

Comment: It only fails if you try to reference **a property** of varname when varname is not defined.

Comment: If varname is not defined then there should be a failure, because you should always define the variables you're using. If you use a variable you didn't declare and you don't catch it in your testing then you can't expect it to do anything other than break

Comment: @lots of people, actually it will fail when `varname` is not **declared**, but not when it is declared but not defined.

Comment: @Box9 - isn't is simply `undefined` in that case? That's a good point though, it depends on what the OP needs. In most cases, I suppose you wouldn't check a global variable, but a property, or a function parameter.

Comment: @Box9 While the actual error is "varname is undefined" ;-) but it's good to precise it. undeclared -> variable is undefined. Untyped -> type if undefined (but variable is defined)

Answer (score 2):

**The original question was this**:  What is the classical way in JavaScript for testing variables so as to avoid crashes?

This may be the classical way, and it's certainly a very practical way:

First, you should never, ever have undeclared variables.  Use [JSLint](http://jslint.com/) to be sure that you don't.

If you believe `a` is numeric, `if (a != null)` will tell you if there's some value in it (though possibly NaN), and `if (a)` will tell you if there's some nonzero value in it.

If you believe `a` is a string, `if (a != null)` will tell you if there's some value in it (though possible the empty string), and `if (a)` will tell you if there's at least one character in the string.

If you believe `a` is an object, `if (a)` will tell you if it's defined.  Corollary: `if (a && a.prop==7)` is a safe way to check the value of a property.

If you have no idea what `a` is supposed to be, then you can still safely test it with `if (a)`, though I can't say for sure how useful the results will be.

(Then again, if you have no idea what `a` is supposed to be, you have a much bigger problem than can be addressed here.)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you have to do with the variable. `null` may or may not be a perfectly acceptable value, depending on the context (but I have to admit I have never fonud a good use for `null` in javascript). Probably the safest thing is to rely on exceptions to catch problems when something go wrong, instead of trying to anticipate errors by checking for existence of variables.

On the other hand, if you compare something to `null` or `undefined` it is a good idea to use the `===` operator, which does not need type coercion.

The simpler check `if(variable)` will check that `variable` is not falsy (that is, it is not `null`, `undefined`, `false`, `0`, `NaN`, `-0` or the empty string).

Finally the method `hasOwnProperty` is often useful when you want to loop over the properties of an object and exclude properties that are inherited from the prototype.

**EDIT** Pay attention that the above refers to undefined variables, that is, variables which are declared like

```
var variable;
```

but are not assigned any value, or missing parameters in functions. One may also want to consider the case of dealing with variables which are undeclared at all. In this case all tests like

```
if(variable);
if(variable === null);
```

and so on will fail, reporting an error. The only safe way I know to deal with this case is to check the type of the variable. That is, the `typeof` operator can gently handle variables which do not exist.

```
if(typeof variable === 'undefined')
```

will be true if either

- `variable` was declared but is undefined, or
- `variable` was not declared at all.

In no case this last check will trigger an error.

Comment: Hellloooo people, "if(varname)" fails if varname is undefined!

Comment: Falsey values include `NaN` and `-0`.

Comment: I really wonder why my answer, which gives a few options, gets -1, while another answer which only lists if(varname) gets +3. In any case, if(varname) will **not** fail if varname is undefined. It fails if varname is not declared, which is another issue. Please document before downvoting!

Comment: @Mike: sorry, I forgot NaN. -0 is the same as 0.

Comment: @Andrea.  `-0` is not the same as `0`.  `1/0 !== 1/-0`.  And `1/Math.min(0, -0) === 1/Math.min(-0, 0)` so the mathematical operators need to preserve the distinction by treating `-0` as comparing before `0`.

Comment: Ouch! I did not know about -0. But I'm in good company: Crockford does not list it among the falsy values (at least in the edition I have)! :-) Thank you

Comment: @Andrea, yeah, quite a few people who know IEEE 754 well have a blindspot around JavaScript numerics because for most code you just treat them like ints.  The reference for this is section 9.2 of the language spec which deals with the abstract "ToBoolean" operator.
Undefined => false; Null => false; Boolean : The result equals the input argument (no conversion); Number : The result is false if the argument is +0, -0, or NaN, otherwise the result is true; String : The result is false if the argument is the empty String (its length is zero), otherwise the result is true; Object => true

Comment: @Andrea, I gave you -1 because I considered you had to take the undeclared issue into account OR insist on the fact varname has to be declared before (remember this website is aimed at everybody, advanced or total newbies). The question talks about "if (typeof(varname) != 'undefined')" which means the type of varname could be undefined (or varname could be undeclared).

Comment: I agree that I should have mentioned it, but I think giving -1 for a correct (although possibly incomplete) answer is unnecessarily harsh. You could just leave a comment and I would have edited the answer.

Comment: @Andrea, I removed my down vote but please edit your answer ;-). I voted down mainly because this is misleading and could be dangerous if reused without declaring variables.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to understand is strict equality vs truthiness or falsiness. Strict uses three equality signs, where as truthiness uses 2.

These are all equivalent:

```
var a = false;
if(!a)
if(a == false)
if(a != true)
if(a == 0)
if(a == "")
```

Using three signs is strict. False means false, not "falsey":

```
var a = false;
if(a === false)
if(a !== true)
if(a !== anything_else)
id(a === 0) // this will be false
```

Next, there is a slight difference between null and undefined. Null means declared but nullified (literally set to "null"), undefined means declared but not set:

```
window.a;
console.log(a); // undefined

window.a = null;
console.log(a); // null
```

Finally, you wouldn't use *typeof* for true or false. That's more for string or object type stuff. And variables within objects are properties, not variables, and treated slightly different.

Comment: Undeclared is different from undefined.

Comment: `==` isn't exactly a truthy comparison - it just allows type coercion. `null` for example is falsey but `false != null`.

Comment: @awm so what would you do to protect against those both likely crash reasons ?

Comment: @Stephane wrote you a long answer (below). :)